# Outputting CRC32 hex from text inside .txt file using C on Ubuntu environment

Tags: c, io, crc, crc32

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                                     
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                                                                                                                       
#include <string.h>                                                                                                                                                                                       
#include <zlib.h>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#define LSIZ 128                                                                                                                                                                                          
#define RSIZ 10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
int main()                                                                                                                                                                                                
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    // gets input from input.txt                                                                                                                                                                              
    char *filename = "input.txt";                                                                                                                                                                             
    FILE *fptr;                                                                                                                                                                                               
    fptr = fopen(filename, "r");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    int i = 0, j, tot = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                    
    char line[RSIZ][LSIZ];
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    // inputs text content into array                                                                                                                                                                         
    while(fgets(line[i], LSIZ, fptr) != NULL)                                                                                                                                                                 
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';                                                                                                                                                                      
        i++;                                                                                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    printf("\n");
                                                                                                                                                                                             
    tot = i;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    printf("\nThe content of the file %s are: \n",filename);                                                                                                                                                  
    for(j = 0; j < tot; ++j)                                                                                                                                                                                          
        printf(" %s\n", line[i]);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

    //convert into hex of crc32                                                                                                                                                                               
    const char *s = line[i];                                                                                                                                                                                  
    printf("%s's crc32 in hex: ",filename);                                                                                                                                                                   
    printf("%lX\n", crc32(0, (const void*)s, strlen(s)));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                         
    }
```

I can't seem to get the code to work as intended. I am using vim while also compiling on an Ubuntu Terminal for this code. I wanted this to get the text from input.txt, store it into the array and create crc32 hex of said input. However, this output is the result:

```
The content of the file input.txt are:

input.txt's crc32 in hex: 0
```

There is definitely something wrong with the char inputting but, after browsing, I seemed to hit the wall on this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like input.txt is an empty file, or there is some other error eading it... since nothing is printed as under 'The content of the file'.  If nothing is in the file, a crc of 0 is reasonable. Also, i at that pointwhere you get `*s = line[i]`, is one past the number of lines you read in.  Help youself debug, `printf("i = %d\n", i);` after you think you read the file.  What if it is zero and nothing was read?

Comment: Hello, the input.txt has my name inside of it, so I believe it is not empty. Let me check for the line[i].

Comment: note nothing was printed in your print contents loop either.  Probably you meant `line[j]` in that printf - again because `i` got a `i++;` at the end of the while loop and is one past the data you read in.

Comment: Normally, I would use `stat()` to get the size of the file, then allocate exactly that much memory, `fopen()` the file in binary mode, then `fread()` the whole file in all at once, and then pass the entire buffer containing the file to `crc32()`.

Comment: Yes, thank you JohnH, I did a mistake on the printing of the array part by not using j :).

Comment: I edited you question and put the answer in the answer post, so you can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*I edited your question, removing the answer you added to it, and posted that answer here.*</sup>

My code is running perfectly now. I will write the the whole thing here for other's reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <zlib.h>

#define LSIZ 128
#define RSIZ 10

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
        // gets input from input.txt
        char *filename = "input.txt";
        FILE *fptr;
        fptr = fopen(filename, "r");

        int i = 0, j, tot = 0;
        char line[RSIZ][LSIZ];

        // inputs text content into array
        while(fgets(line[i], LSIZ, fptr) != NULL)
        {
                line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';
                i++;
        }
        tot = i;
        printf("The content of the file %s are: ",filename);
        for(j = 0; j < tot; ++j)
                printf("%s\n", line[j]);

        //convert into hex of crc32
        const char *s = line[0];

        printf("%s's crc32 in hex: ",filename);
        printf("%lX\n", crc32(0, (const void*)s, strlen(s)));

        fclose(fptr);
        return 0;
}
```

This is the output with "Hello World" inside input.txt file:

```
The content of the file input.txt are: Hello World
input.txt's crc32 in hex: 4A17B156
```

Comment: As this is not really your answer, you should make it a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/616624) post.

Comment: Please see [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267434/6045800). As Adrian mentioned, making a CW is the proper thing to do in this situation